# pcntl_fork child process memory

Tags: php, memory

I see strange behavior when forked via `pcntl_fork`.

Simple script of a running daemon

```php
pcntl_fork();
while (true) {
    sleep(1);
}
```

Let's compare the memory usage of a parent and a child
[image: memory-usage]

It can be seen that the child process takes up about a third less memory. If you dig a little deeper and compare the output of `pmap -x 1172 1173` for both processes, we will see the following picture
[image: memory-allocated-diff]
If I understand correctly, then at startup PHP allocates memory with a margin for itself, as well as for all its modules, and this margin is quite significant, especially if you have many daemons running on one instance.

It turns out in such a tricky way you can cut the memory usage of your daemon.

```php
if (pcntl_fork() > 0) {
    die();
}
while (true) {
    sleep(1);
}
```

What problem can be here? Only that you have to spend time on memory allocation if necessary?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because when the main proccess start, he need to import some config files, like php.ini, some libaries, ...

When you fork the main proccess, the child proccess reset some params ([fork(2) — Linux manual page](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/fork.2.html)), like the parent's memory locks, the pending signals, some outstanding asynchronous I/O operations, ...

And like the child process has been running a very little time and he hasn't done almost anything, it hasn't needed so much memory but if you use the child process as main process and the end, the child process will use more memory than the parent.

So, you may thinks that fork your main process after a while, to reset this params could be a good idea, but it isn't because:

- In this example you are comparing two process that both of then they have done almost nothing, so here the most memory usage is for auxiliary registres, but it's not common in a normal execution.
- You'll spend resources to fork a process, especially if you have a lot of variables, so you'll need more resources to fork the process that you will save resetting the params.
- Even if you save some memory, your code will become very complicated so understand and to maintain.

I hope to have helped you.

Comment: > if you use the child process as main process and the end, the child process will use more memory than the parent.

@Pericodes, can you explain, why the child process will use more memory?

Comment: The main process use more memory than the child process because it has made more things, like import files, so it has needed to save some registres on memory (Like the pointers to the files that it has imported) and the child process has made nothing, so it has not any registres on memory. When you will use the child process and will open some files (like `requires`), it will save the pointers on memory that you can see [here](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/fork.2.html) it will use the same memory that the main process would use.

Comment: And also you will have spent some memory and CPU to fork the process that I'm sure that it's much more resources that you'll save forking the process.

Comment: Imagine that you have a car (The main process), you drive with it for a while and after that you clone  it (Fork the main process) and **reset** the kilometers  (**Reset** all the params). If you count the kilometers  in this moment, the cloned car will have less kilometers (The child process uses less memory) but it is just because you have reseted it.If you makes your cloned car your main car (The child process becomes the main process) after a while the cloned car will have more kilometers (The child process will use more memory). I hope it will be easier to understand like this. :))

Answer (score 0):

First of all you have to understand PHP [pcntl_fork](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.pcntl-fork.php) which says - Forks the currently running process

> The pcntl_fork() function creates a child process that differs from
> the parent process only in its PID and PPID. Please see your system's
> **fork(2) man page** for specific details as to how fork works on your
> system.

What is here important to note that you have to understand your system Fork(2) process. So Fork is OS dependent

According to [this](https://man.openbsd.org/fork.2) page there are some fork(2) examples

> fork() causes creation of a new process. The new process (child
> process) is an exact copy of the calling process (parent process)
> except for the following:
>
> - The child process has a unique process ID, which also does not match any existing process group ID.
> - The child process has a different parent process ID (i.e., the process ID of the parent process).
> - The child process has a single thread.
> - The child process has its own copy of the parent's descriptors. These descriptors reference the same underlying objects, so that, for
>   instance, file pointers in file objects are shared between the child
>   and the parent, so that an lseek(2) on a descriptor in the child
>   process can affect a subsequent read(2) or write(2) by the parent.
>   This descriptor copying is also used by the shell to establish
>   standard input and output for newly created processes as well as to
>   set up pipes.
> - The child process has no fcntl(2)-style file locks.
> - The child process' resource utilizations are set to 0; see getrusage(2).
> - All interval timers are cleared; see setitimer(2).
> - The child process' semaphore undo values are set to 0; see semop(2).
> - The child process' pending signals set is empty.
> - The child process has no memory locks; see mlock(2) and mlockall(2).
>
> In general, the child process should call _exit(2) rather than
> exit(3). Otherwise, any stdio buffers that exist both in the parent
> and child will be flushed twice. Similarly, _exit(2) should be used to
> prevent atexit(3) routines from being called twice (once in the parent
> and once in the child).